# How to print the Google Distance Matrix Results Json Data

Tags: php, json

How to print the Results from Google Distance matrix iam Getting a results like this:

```
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "4,8 km",
              "value" : 4820
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "17 minutes",
              "value" : 1038
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "11,1 km",
              "value" : 11064
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "25 minutes",
              "value" : 1506
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
```

And My Php Code to print The Output is

```
$json = file_get_contents($url); 
$result = json_decode($json, true); 
for($i=0; $i<count($result['rows']); $i++) {

    echo "Kilometers " . $result['rows'][$i]["elements"][$i]['distance']['text'];

}
```

.Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you haven't included all the response, the method invlolved in the retrieval of the data nor the final desired output it is tricky to answer but I hope the following will give guidance on how to render the output.

This uses example data from the interwebs rather than the partial example code given in the question - a bit rough perhaps but...

```
$res='{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "Commons Way, Bridgewater, NJ 08807, USA",
      "Morris Turnpike, Short Hills, NJ 07078, USA",
      "Monmouth Mall, Eatontown, NJ 07724, USA",
      "Garden State Plaza Blvd, Paramus, NJ 07652, USA",
      "Newport Centre Mall, Jersey City, NJ 07302, USA"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "75 Ninth Ave, New York, NY 10011, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "68.8 km",
                  "value" : 68781
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "56 mins",
                  "value" : 3334
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "1 hour 1 min",
                  "value" : 3687
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "34.8 km",
                  "value" : 34806
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "36 mins",
                  "value" : 2138
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "41 mins",
                  "value" : 2487
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "86.3 km",
                  "value" : 86322
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 hour 6 mins",
                  "value" : 3930
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "1 hour 7 mins",
                  "value" : 4044
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "32.3 km",
                  "value" : 32278
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "33 mins",
                  "value" : 2009
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "35 mins",
                  "value" : 2082
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "6.9 km",
                  "value" : 6879
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "19 mins",
                  "value" : 1113
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "24 mins",
                  "value" : 1444
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}';

/* return as an object for easier notation */
$json=json_decode( $res, false );
$origins = $json->origin_addresses;
$destinations=$json->destination_addresses;
/*  if there are multiple rows, use a loop and `$rows[$i]` etc */
$elements=$json->rows[0]->elements;
foreach( $elements as $i => $obj ){

    echo '
    <div>
        <h5>From: '.$origins[ 0 ].' to '.$destinations[ $i ].'</h5>
        Distance: '.$obj->distance->text.',
        Duration:'.$obj->duration->text.',
        In traffic: '.$obj->duration_in_traffic->text.',
        Status: '.$obj->status.'
    </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a nested foreach, this is not the only way to render the output but it works.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$result = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($result['rows'][0] as $elements => $element) {

    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['distance']['text'];
        echo $value['duration']['text'];
        echo $value['status'];

        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

All we are doing is accessing a multi-dimensional array using $key => $value and then $value[$key] notation... I would suggest a crash course on how to handle arrays in php, this one is great: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57y5maglayQ

You can also look at the overall structure of your array by writing `echo '<pre>', var_dump($result), '</pre>;'` which will show your array => key pairs.